# Click to edit fires all events again everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple click to edit function for a page. Most of it works apart from when you click and edit multiple events. It always wanted to send the previous events again with the new click. Here's the code:

```
    $('.editable').click(function() {

        var that = $(this);
        if (that.find('input').length > 0) {
            return;
        }

        var currentText = that.text();
        var name = that.data('field');
        var contact_id = that.closest('[data-id]').data('id');
        console.log(contact_id);
        console.log(that);
        that.empty();

        console.log(name);

        var $input = $('<input>').val( $.trim(currentText))
            .css({
                'position': 'relative',
                top: '0px',
                //left: '0px',
                width: that.width(),
                height: that.height(),
                opacity: 1,
                padding: '15px',
                'margin-bottom': '0'
            });

        $(this).append($input);


        $(document).on('blur','.editable', function(){

            that.text( $input.val());
            console.log(contact_id);
            console.log(name);

            that.find('input').remove();


        });
```

p.s would you know why the on blur makes you need to click the element twice before clicking off to close it?

```
<div class="large-12" id="reviewsNeeded--main" data-id="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">
    <div class="collapse">
        <div class="reviewsNeededTable--name large-12 columns" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
                <div class="large-5 no-pad-left editable" id="name" data-field="name">
                    <?php echo $result['first_name'] . " " . $result['last_name']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="large-5 no-pad-left editable" style="font-size: 0.80rem; margin-top: 5px; color: #6c22ca;"
                     data-field="company">
                    <?php echo get_term_by('id', $result['company'], 'publishers')->name; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns no-pad-left">
                <div class="large-12">
                    <button class="delete-btn" data-id="<?php echo $result['id'] ?>">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both; margin: 5px 0"></div>
                <div class="large-12">
                    <a class="show--meta">
                        <button>Show More</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="reviewsNeededTable--request large-3 columns">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add your html code as well?

Comment: Yes, adding html will increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you click you are adding a new blur handler on *any* `.editable`, with `that` scoped to the current context.  It sounds like you want to change:

```
$(document).on('blur','.editable', function(){
```

to

```
$(that).one('blur', function(){
```

so that it fires only once (`.one`) and only on the current input.

Comment: Or move the blur handler out of the other handler.

Comment: Using .one worked perfectly! Just need to work out why clicking the element and clicking off won't work until you click the element again.